# Codeception and Selenium 2 warning

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception

I have a lot of warning when trying to run Selenium2 tests through codeception. The tests work though.

These are the warning if someone can lead me on the right way to correct :

```
C:\Users\Bebop\Documents\Site Internet\Sites\prestashop1.5.6\modules\paypal>php
codecept.phar run Selenium
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.7.0.2
Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann.
PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in phar://C:/Users/Bebo
p/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src
/Codeception/Module/Selenium2.php on line 70
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\Users\Bebop\Documents\Site Internet\Sites\prestashop1.5.6\m
odules\paypal\codecept.phar:0
PHP   2. require_once() C:\Users\Bebop\Documents\Site Internet\Sites\prestashop1
.5.6\modules\paypal\codecept.phar:7
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Docu
ments/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/codecept:
29
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Do
cuments/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/vendor/
symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() phar://C:/Users/B
ebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/
vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/
Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/vendo
r/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:897
PHP   7. Codeception\Command\Run->execute() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site
 Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/vendor/symfony/cons
ole/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
PHP   8. Codeception\Command\Run->runSuites() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Si
te Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/C
ommand/Run.php:83
PHP   9. Codeception\Codecept->runSuite() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site I
nternet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Comma
nd/Run.php:115
PHP  10. Codeception\SuiteManager->__construct() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents
/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src/Codeceptio
n/Codecept.php:124
PHP  11. Codeception\SuiteManager->initializeModules() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Doc
uments/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src/Code
ception/SuiteManager.php:48
PHP  12. Codeception\Module\Selenium2->_initialize() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Docum
ents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src/Codece
ption/SuiteManager.php:62
PHP  13. array_merge() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prest
ashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Module/Selenium2.php:70

Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Doc
uments/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src/Code
ception/Module/Selenium2.php on line 70

Call Stack:
    0.0117    1074720   1. {main}() C:\Users\Bebop\Documents\Site Internet\Sites
\prestashop1.5.6\modules\paypal\codecept.phar:0
    0.0208    1373568   2. require_once('phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site In
ternet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/codecept') C:\Users\Be
bop\Documents\Site Internet\Sites\prestashop1.5.6\modules\paypal\codecept.phar:7

    0.0667    4331624   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() phar://C
:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codec
ept.phar/codecept:29
    0.0785    4941624   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() phar:/
/C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/cod
ecept.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
    0.0791    4941624   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
 phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/pay
pal/codecept.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.p
hp:191
    0.0792    4941624   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() phar
://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/c
odecept.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:89
7
    0.0802    4941992   7. Codeception\Command\Run->execute() phar://C:/Users/Be
bop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/v
endor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
    0.1596    9010384   8. Codeception\Command\Run->runSuites() phar://C:/Users/
Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar
/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:83
    0.1597    9010720   9. Codeception\Codecept->runSuite() phar://C:/Users/Bebo
p/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src
/Codeception/Command/Run.php:115
    0.1675    9175200  10. Codeception\SuiteManager->__construct() phar://C:/Use
rs/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.p
har/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:124
    0.1756   10263064  11. Codeception\SuiteManager->initializeModules() phar://
C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/code
cept.phar/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php:48
    0.1867   11096264  12. Codeception\Module\Selenium2->_initialize() phar://C:
/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codece
pt.phar/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php:62
    0.1914   11529024  13. array_merge() phar://C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site In
ternet/Sites/prestashop1.5.6/modules/paypal/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Module
/Selenium2.php:70
```

============= At this time the tests begins

```
←[1mSelenium Tests (1) ←[0m-----------------------------------------------------
--------------
Trying to ←[35;1mlogin in backoffice←[0m (PrestaShopModuleListCest.install_the_m
odule)       Ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------


Time: 27.79 seconds, Memory: 16.25Mb

←[30;42m←[2KOK (1 test, 0 assertions)
←[0m←[2K
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Found out what was wrong :

I had a missing space in my Selenium.suite.yml which did not convert my capabilities in an array :

```
    capabilities:
            unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
```

This was the good thing to do